# Why C# inherited static members cannot be found in propType.GetMethod with FlattenHierarchy flag?

Tags: c#

I have the following block:

```
public abstract class AParsable<T> where T : AParsable<T>
{
    public static T Parse(string input)
    {
        return JSON.TryParse<T>(input);
    }
}
```

which will be used in this way (Edited with full usage intention. TL;DR: parse incoming request body into a request data class.

```
    public static T ParseBody<T>(this System.Web.HttpRequestBase request) where T: new()
    {
        var instance = new T();
        var publicProps = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var stringType = typeof(string);
        foreach (var prop in publicProps)
        {
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            if (!prop.CanWrite) continue;

            var input = request.Form[prop.Name];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) continue;

            if (propType == typeof(string))
            {
                prop.SetValue(instance, input, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var parse = propType.GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { stringType }, null);
                if (parse != null) // I always get null here
                {
                    var value = parse.Invoke(null, new object[] { input });
                    prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

I always get parse as null for the following code

```
public class TreeNodeArray : AParsable<TreeNodeArray>
{
    public List<TreeNodeWrapper> nodes { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:** Would appreciate it if someone could point out a better way to dynamically parse the request body in .NET MVC into a class instance.

**Update 2**: In a controller it would be used like this:

```
internal class MyRequestModel {
    public TreeNodeArray selectedNodes { get; set; }
    public bool isForAllNodes { get; set; }
}

var requestData = Request.ParseBody<MyRequestModel>();
requestData.selectedNodes == null;
```

Comment: How propType is initialized?

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail on usage intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've omitted `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` from your sample code (though it's in the title). This needs to be included in your code. Working version:

```
var parse = propType
                .GetMethod("Parse", 
                    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, 
                    null, new Type[] { stringType }, null
                );
```

Comment: So putting together `FlattenHierarchy` | `Public` | `Static` did the job, I tried everything individually `FlattenHierarchy`, `Public`, `Static` but it seems the combination of them is the way to go. Please update your answer or create new one so I can mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @bigopon I'm not sure I follow; my answer already includes all three of the flags together

Comment: In the answer, you state that `propType` here is the type `List<TreeNodeWrapper>`, which is incorrect. It is `TreeNodeArray`, of the property `selectedNodes` in internal class `MyRequestModel`

Comment: @bigopon Ah, yes - I misread, I was under the impression that the code was invoked on `TreeNodeArray` rather than `MyRequestModel`. I'll remove that part